# Installing python (same version) on accident twice

Tags: python, scipy, reinstall

I accidentally installed python 2.7 again on my mac (mountain lion), when trying to install scipy using macports:

> sudo port install py27-scipy
>
> --->  Computing dependencies for py27-scipy
>
> --->  Dependencies to be installed: SuiteSparse gcc47 cctools cctools-headers llvm-3.3 libffi llvm_select cloog gmp isl gcc_select
>   ld64 libiconv libmpc mpfr libstdcxx ppl glpk zlib py27-nose
>   nosetests_select py27-setuptools **python27** bzip2 db46 db_select
>   gettext expat ncurses libedit openssl python_select sqlite3 py27-numpy
>   fftw-3 swig-python swig pcre

I am still using my original install of python (and matplotlib and numpy etc), without scipy. How do I remove this new version? It is taking up ~2Gb space.

Comment: Does the new install creating some kind of problem ?

Comment: No, just space. I also can't really find where it's installed...but I believe it has scipy installed along with it. Is there a way to remove it or should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `sudo port uninstall python27`?

Comment: er. won't that uninstall my perfectly happy original install of python that I like? it seems like that might just uninstall all versions of python 2.7.

Comment: How did the "original" Python get installed?  using MacPorts ("port") or some other way?

Comment: Well then `port uninstall` is not going to uninstall that version.  It will only uninstall things that  were installed with `port install`.

Comment: Excellent, I will try what you said!